# More Detailed Billing Information of GCS Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-billing

I have multiple GKE clusters with logically separated K8s objects using namespaces, each namespace has GCS bucket attached to it (Statefulset)
I wanted to know billing information about each namespace and what each namespace costs for resources usage.
I found very useful feature called "GKE Metering" and yea it showed up some useful information about CPU and Memory billing info for each namespace by gathering billing information and import it into BigQuery, then I can visualize the results using Google Data Studio for example.

The Question Is:

1. How can I get billing information of each GCS bucket which attached
   to each namespace to be visualised?
2. How to get billing information
   fo each namespace usage of Filestore Instance?

Any help will be appreciated 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to [add a label on your GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-bucket-labels)

Then to export [the billing to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery)

And to get the data like that in BigQuery

```
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.exportBillingTable` 
WHERE "<Your Label Key>" IN UNNEST(labels.key)
```

You can perform "group by", "sum", filter on the label key or the label value,...

Comment: I added labels to GCS buckets I have, and exported the data to BigQuery... I can see in the tables there are data about "Compute Instances", "Cloud SQL", and everything but I cannot find anything related to GCS buckets

Comment: Wait a day. It took  about 20H for me between the label set up and the propagation in BigQuery billing table

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information 
another question please, Am I being billed for GCS buckets even if it is empty?
As for testing purposes I created two empty buckets and not showing in the table after more than 24 hours
all resources appeared except empty buckets
is that right or even if it is empty it must appear in BigQuery?

Comment: Yes, empty bucket don't appear. But you can put a very very small file, only to generate few dollars per months (the minimum is 10e-9, so file of few bytes is enough to see an entry in the billing but you will be never really billing for so few.)

Comment: That's Great News!!
Thanks a Lot ✨

Answer (score 0):

This is now available without the labeling step! The update was released in [February 13, 2024](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/release-notes#February_13_2024)

```
View granular cost data from Cloud Storage usage in Cloud Billing exports to BigQuery

You can now view granular Cloud Storage bucket-level cost data in the Cloud Billing Detailed cost export. Use the resource.global_name field in the export to view and filter your detailed Cloud Storage bucket usage.
```